# Merge Files over multiple folders using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a directory structure as below.

Root_dir

```
   Sub_dir1

   Sub_dir2

   ....
```

Here I have multiple sub folders in the Root directory. Now each sub folder contains a message.csv file. I want to append them and create a new csv file.

Comment: Apologies for what may be a silly question but I assume all the CSVs have the same columns? Also, do any of them have column headings? Makes a difference to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that all CSVs have the same columns something like this should work:

```
$root = 'C:\path\to\Root_dir'
$csv  = 'C:\path\to\output.csv'

Get-ChildItem $root -Filter 'message.csv' -Recurse | % {
  Import-Csv $_.FullName 
} | Export-Csv $csv -NoTypeInformation
```

To remove duplicates from the output try this instead:

```
$root = 'C:\path\to\Root_dir'
$csv  = 'C:\path\to\output.csv'

Get-ChildItem $root -Filter 'message.csv' -Recurse | % {
  Import-Csv $_.FullName 
} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | select -Unique | Out-File $csv
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Can you please guide me how to select distinct rows after merging csv files based on the ID column?

Comment: Do you want to filter the result before writing it to the output file? If so, why didn't you mention that in your question? What are your criteria?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not mention duplication criteria at the start of my question, As I got to learn about duplication error after I merged the files. Removing duplicates is fine at any stage of merging, only concern is performance. After merging all csv files, size of merged file grows to couple of GB's.

Comment: Here unique works on multiple records with same all column values, what parameters I need to add just to constraint unique id value?

Comment: You could use `sort -Unique ID | Export-Csv` instead of `ConvertTo-Csv | select -Unique | Out-File`. However, if the other fields of records with the same ID differ, you're going to lose data that way.